# Is there a Jackson annotation for setting the JSON object name on a target child object?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Supposing I have the following JSON, (contrived to hide any reference to my project):

```
{
  "name": "Johnny Bravo",
  "addresses": {
    "home": {
      "street": "123 Any Street",
      "city": "Anytown",
      "state": "AA",
      "zip": "99999"
    },
    "work": {
      "street": "9870 Some Boulevard",
      "city": "Someville",
      "state": "AA",
      "zip": "98765"
    }
  }
}
```

If I deserialize this into a Person POJO, which have individual home and work fields that are an Address POJO, and on Address, in addition to street, city, state, and zip, there exists a "type" field, is there a Jackson annotation which lets me access the object names ("home", work") and sets them on the Address.type field?

Comment: Can the number of addresses vary? I mean, is it a dynamic element here so that suddenly some other type of address may occur?

Comment: Not sure that the number of addresses matters, as Address.type would just be the name of the object again. This is essentially just giving the child access to who it is, in regard to the parent.